# Push Notification: Update app with new Parse App

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to release a new version of my app changing the Parse App. If I just install the app all new users appear in this new Parse App. But if update the app with this new version (with different parse app - applicationId and clientKey) the users did not appear in this new Parse App.

Here is the code where I send the new installation to parse:

```
Parse.initialize(AppgradeApplication.getContext(),getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
ParseInstallation currentInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
currentInstallation.saveInBackground();
```

What I need to do to change the Parse App?

Comment: The `saveInBackground` method should know that the installation didn't change since last time it was saved, and thus not saving at all. Try setting any value to any key of the installation before saving it.

Comment: I read some people suggesting to set the `Installation`'s `objectId` to `null` before saving it. But this must be done only one time: `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().setObjectId(null); ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();`. Not sure if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing: clear parse installation from disk and memory. To do that, I needed to access protected methods from parse. So, I created a class with the path `com.parse` called `ParseClearUtility` and then I was able to access protected method from parse. See code below:

```
package com.parse;

public class ParseClearUtility {

    public static void clear() {
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallationController().clearFromDisk();
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallationController().clearFromMemory();
    }

}
```

This code clear parse installation EVERY TIME a user opens the app. So, when initializing parse I check the version of the app:

```
Parse.initialize(context, BuildConfig.PARSE_APP_ID, BuildConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

ParseInstallation currentInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
List<String> channels = currentInstallation.getList(CHANNELS);
if(!currentInstallation.getString(COLUMN_APP_VERSION).equals(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)) {
     ParseClearUtility.clear();
}
```